# Доступ из Python к Access

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, access

Как получить доступ из python к базе данных Access "Борей"  и извлечь из нее данные?

Comment: ODBC или ещё что нибудь (ADODB, OLEDB или что там ещё есть...)

Answer (score 1):

COM через win32 вот так: [Driving MS Access from python](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2006-March/004412.html).